# MariaDB para quando tenho muitos acessos no wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb

Tenho um site em Wordpress, usava o MySQL antes no CentOS, resolvi migrar para um Debian 7 com MariaDB, mas quando tenho mais de 30 acessos simultâneos no blog, o banco para.

Segue abaixo meu `my.cfg`:

```
# MariaDB database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this file to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#local-infile   = 0

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_connections     = 50
max_user_connections    = 25
connect_timeout     = 10
wait_timeout        = 45
interactive_timeout = 45
max_allowed_packet  = 2M
thread_cache_size       = 128
thread_concurrency  = 2
thread_cache        = 1
#sort_buffer_size   = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
table_cache     = 250
tmp_table_size      = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover          = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 16M
sort_buffer     = 1M
#join_buffer        = 1M
#max_join_size      = 2M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit       = 512KB
query_cache_size        = 128M
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
#log_bin_index      = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
# slaves
#relay_log      = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
innodb_log_file_size    = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 1
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Como é que você "mediu" os 30 acessos simultâneos?

Comment: Seu max_connections tá 50 e max_user_connections 25 na configuração, mas isso significaria todos abrindo a página ao mesmo tempo (e não simplesmente navegando). Seria bom dar mais detalhes na pergunta, para que fique mais fácil alguém ajudar.

Comment: O banco para e da alguma mensagem de erro? Ou é o Servidor HTTP que parou?

Comment: Um palpite seria que o Wordpress está consumindo muitas conexões simultâneas, seja por mal configuração ou plugins gerando conexões adicionais. 
Eu recomendo você tentar usar alguma ferramenta como o MySQL Workbench para monitorar o número de conexões abertas em apenas 1 acesso, multiplicando este número pelos usuários simultâneos pode-se exceder o limite do seu banco.

Comment: Já tentou acessar o banco de dados e executar SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST para ver o que está acontecendo? Já viu se as conexões que você está abrindo estão sendo fechadas? Verificou os arquivos de log? /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log, /var/log/mysql/mysql.log, /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log?

Comment: Post os trechos de log dos períodos que vc sabe que o banco caiu.

Comment: Deveria estar suspensa a pergunta até o @DanielBernardo postar mais detalhes