# Wordpress lento e com erros de acesso ao banco de dados

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tudo bom pessoal,

Tinha feito outra pergunta, mas consegui identificar algumas consultas que estão consumindo muito tempo de execução.

Desenvolvi um tema para um portal de noticias, e em cada área eu carrego noticias de uma determinada categoria.
Mas como algumas postagens (noticias) utilizam mais de uma categoria, preciso tomar cuidado para não obter dados repetidos, neste caso utilizo a opção post__not_in

Vejam um exemplo:

```
<?php
//$posts_ID é uma variavel que guarda dos IDs dos posts ja exibidos em consultas anteriores a esta.
$posts_planeta_diario = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post__not_in' => $posts_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'cat' => 3946
    )
);
$return_while = 1;
    while ($posts_planeta_diario->have_posts()):
        $posts_planeta_diario->the_post();

        //armazena os IDs resgatados 
        $posts_ID[] = get_the_ID();

        //evitar quebra de layout
        if ($return_while == 3)
            $style_planeta_diario = 'style="margin-right:0px"'
?>
        <li class="liNoticiasPlanetaDiario02" <?php echo $style_planeta_diario; ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-205x145') ?></a>
            <article>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </article>
        </li>

<?php 
        $return_while ++;
    endwhile; 
?>
```

Neste exemplo demonstra o que acontece no home page do site.
Meu banco de dados atualmente tem 1gb.
Quando tenho muitos acessos simultâneos da aquele famoso erro de banco de dados (ERRO AO CONECTAR AO BANCO DE DADOS).

A logica que usei acima está correta, pode ser este tipo de chamada que possa está ocasionando lentidão e erro de banco ?

Comment: Cara aparentemente não tem nada de errado com sua lógica, verifique se no seu wordpress tem muitos crons. Pergunta básica o seu servidor da conta da sua aplicação?

Comment: Provavelmente o `max_user_connections`/`max_connections` do MySQL, que limita o número de processos simultâneos. Se for isto, então esses tópicos são relacionados: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182000/exceeded-the-max-user-connections-resource-c-sql/ e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46433/mariadb-para-quando-tenho-muitos-acessos-no-wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se já foi resolvido. 
Mas vocês esqueceu de colocar o `wp_reset_postdata()` no final depois do `endwhile` para mais informações do pra que/porque usar [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

Outra coisa que não entendi direito é o que você tem a necessidade de incrementar o loop. Isso não é bom. 
Você pode fazer a mesma coisa que fez aqui `$style_planeta_diario = 'style="margin-right:0px"'` usando apenas css asssim:

```
p:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right:0px
}
```

Fazendo isso é menos um loop que seu código vai fazer e vai melhorar bastante a performance.